# How do I simply output a dollar amount?

Tags: c#, decimal

I'm starting out trying to learn code, using visual studio and a c# book. It doesn't go over how to change a double to a dollar amount.
The following is the program I have so far (an assignment). How can I either change the format of my output (WITHOUT adding using system.globalization;) Or make it where the output will always read a 1.1 as $1.10 and 1.5678 as $1.57. For example if I were to put that I work 39 hours at 10.50 an hour.

```
    {
        //Declare all variables:
        double Hours;
        double Rate;
        double GrossPay;
        double FederalTax;
        double StateTax;
        double SocialSecurity;
        double NetPay;
        double TotalTax;

        //Introduction:
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Pay Calculator!!!");

        //User input of hours:
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the hours you worked this pay period: ");
        Hours = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        //User input for rate:
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your rate of pay: ");
        Rate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        //Calculations
        GrossPay = Hours * Rate;
        FederalTax = GrossPay * 0.20d;
        StateTax = GrossPay * 0.05d;
        SocialSecurity = GrossPay * 0.062d;
        NetPay = GrossPay - FederalTax - StateTax - SocialSecurity;
        TotalTax = FederalTax + StateTax + SocialSecurity;

        //OutPut
        Console.WriteLine($"Your gross pay is: ${GrossPay}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Your federal tax obligation is: ${FederalTax}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Your state tax obligation is: ${StateTax}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Your social security obligation is: ${SocialSecurity}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Your total tax obligation is: $ {TotalTax}");
        Console.WriteLine($"This will bring your total net pay to: ${NetPay}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You say "decimal" but declared a "float", can you clarify what you really mean here? You do know there is a different type called `decimal` right?

Comment: It should cover how to format a decimal number, the rest is just adding the dollar sign in front. Probably using `'$'0.00` as format string would do it.

Comment: If you want to work with currency, it would be better to use `decimal` rather than `float` to start with.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`ToString("C")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f71z6k0c(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to format as a currency value. First add the following line to your using statements:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Then:

```
Console.WriteLine(FavoriteNumber.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
```

Result:

```
$11.88
```

Answer (score 0):

it is so simple
just use string.format function to give a custom format to string

example:

```
decimal[] amounts = { 16305.32m, 18794.16m };

Console.WriteLine("   Beginning Balance           Ending Balance");

Console.WriteLine("   {0,-28:C2}{1,14:C2}", amounts[0], amounts[1]);
```

this code will display this output:

```
// Displays:

//        Beginning Balance           Ending Balance

//        $16,305.32                      $18,794.16
```

Answer (score 0):

ToString with following format specifier ("C", en-US).
123.456 ("C", en-US) -> $123.46
More info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx